# F# autocomplete doesn't start until autocompleting members

Tags: visual-studio, f#

In visual studio and monodevelop, F# autocomplete doesn't start until you start looking at class or namespace members.

For example, here autocomplete won't start:

```
Syst
```

But here it will:

```
System.TimeSp
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic completion window does, to an extent, obstruct code and irritate the programmer. Before any namespace, module, or type has been specified, the amount of choices is large, so the costs often outweigh the benefits.

- A shortcut, normally Control+Space in Visual Studio, allows to try completion at any time, so the feature is quickly available when needed.
- Many programmers open large namespaces, with huge amounts of defined identifiers.
- The completion window is smart, in that it offers identifiers that may not start with the letters already typed. This further increases the amount of candidates.
- Making automatic completion dependent on the amount of remaining candidate identifiers would not be very intuitive and possibly distracting.

While I don't know whether this is the official reasoning, the current behavior seems like a reasonable choice. It is a good compromise between speed and used attention in the vast majority of situations.

I use the Control+Space shortcut a lot. In my opinion, a useful improvement would be an introduction to the most useful shortcuts in the IDEs; many programmers lose time because they aren't aware of them.

Comment: If it gets in the way, why isn't there an option to turn it on again if someone does prefer getting the autocomplete list? A big feature I like in ReSharper is that it lists all types regardless of what's in the list of usings at the top.

Comment: @LaylConway I'm not a developer of VS, but I can say that pressing Control+Space doesn't take a lot of time, and it also completes the entire expression if there is only one choice remaining. After getting used to it, I can't say I have any need to change the behavior. It might be a question of habit, or depend on the use case though.

Comment: While I'm unsatisfied with the reasoning to why they might disable it in F# compared to other languages, and only in this specific case, this answer does give a decent way to continue the autocomplete-heavy workflow I'm used to so I'll mark it as an answer.